# Check Existence of Blob based on Pattern match in Azure Blob Storage using Python in Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Is there a way to check if file exists in a Azure BLOB container using Python based on pattern using Azure Function? I have different files incoming and I need to process them based on "FileName" Parameter. The Files dropped on the container would come with appended date. I need to check if the file Exists, then work over it.

Sample Files at container =>

1. API_File1_20202008.CSV
2. API_File2_20202008.CSV
3. API_File3_20202008.CSV

If Parameter passed in Function = > API_File1.
Then the function should check if any blob in a specified with API_File1* exists, then process.

For Local OS I was able to use the following.

```
for name in glob.glob(SourceFolder +'/' + FileName + '*.CSV'):
    print(name)
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, you can use the code below to implement it on azure.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice import BlockBlobService


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    #just focus on below part
    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name="<your storage name>", account_key="<storage key>")

    if block_blob_service.exists("<container name>", "file5.csv"):
            print("========found file=======");
    else:
            print("========not exist========");
    #just focus on the part above

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

Before run the code, you need to install the modules. **Do not** install `pip install azure-storage-blob`, I test with install `azure-storage-blob` but it occurs some problem. You can install `pip install azure==4.0.0` (it may take some time) in your virtual environment in "Terminal" window, and then the code can run success.

===================================**Update**==================================

I don't think we can query the file name by `"File5" + "*.CSV"` directly. But I can provide a workaround for your reference. Then function get the request parameter `fileName` and then use the code below:

```
files = [blob for blob in block_blob_service.list_blobs("testcontainer") if blob.name.startswith(fileName)]

for file in files:
    logging.info(file.name)
```

The code is used to get all of the file which start with the `fileName` you send to the function.

Comment: Shen, As mentioned File5 can will have a date suffix, I tried the following but it doesn't work as expected.    FileName = "File5" + '*' + ".CSV"
    if block_blob_service.exists("Container", FileName ):

Comment: @Akshay Sorry, I thought the date is included in the FileName. So you want fuzzy search ?

Comment: Yes. I would be storing the Files names (File1, File2, File3) somewhere and will using the generic "Azure Function" whenever required by sending File Name parameter.  The function should check if File (e.g. File1_20200821) exists, then work over it.

Comment: @Akshay The date in file name is uncertain ? Or just use current date ?

Comment: Yes. It might not be Current Date. However, there would be only one file with "File1" as prefix. I feel It's better to create a solution which is just looking for wildard and not specific date !

Comment: @Akshay Please check the "Update" in my answer. Does this meet your needs ?

Comment: @Akshay You can optimize the code to `blob.name.startswith(fileName + "_")`

Comment: @Shen, It does work. Thank you. Me being greedy, wanted to know if the File1 has a prefix as well. How can that be handled ? Any suggestion for that as well ?

Comment: @Akshay I will do some research on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220200/discussion-between-akshay-and-hury-shen).